# How do I correctly control or do something to placeholder on focus of a forms field?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a signup form with 3 fields:

Username

Email

Password

On most browsers when a user clicks on a particular field, the placeholder value displayed is blanked out so the user can type and if they type nothing and come out of the field the placeholder text re-appears. Anyway some browsers e.g. chrome don't hide the placeholder text onfocus so I had to write some javascript to take care of this.

I'm quite new to javascript but to me the code I've written to deal with this doesn't seem right. I have a feeling it could be shorter and better.

For each field I have this inside a document ready function:

```
$("#field_id").focusin(function() {
  $(this)[0].placeholder = "";
});
$("#field_id").focusout(function() {
  $(this)[0].placeholder = "Enter email";
});
```

My html:

```
<p><input class="signupFields" data-validate="true" id="user_username" name="user[username]" placeholder="Username" size="30" type="text" /></p>
 <p><input class="signupFields" data-validate="true" id="user_email" name="user[email]" placeholder="Email" size="30" type="text" /> </p>
<p><input class="signupFields" data-validate="true" id="user_password" name="user[password]" placeholder="Password" size="30" type="password" /> </p>
```

So imagine that times 3 .. Seems like a lot of code for such a simple requirement. Also I really don't like the fact that I'm trying to mimic javascripts document.getElementById. There must be a way I can do this in a more jQuery like way. Not liking the [0].

Can any body give me an example of a cleaner way of doing this exact same thing?

Kind regards

Comment: Why are you worrying about Chrome's behaviour? At the first keypress the `placeholder` text is removed and the user's entered text is displayed.

Comment: I wouldn't say I'm worrying. It's just what I decided I want. I have gone out of my way to make sure my website acts the same on every browser I have tested in. Some people wouldn't bother..others would. I just happen to be one of those that would.

Comment: Fair enough. I tend to presume that people that use a particular browser tend to become accustomed to that browser's quirks and UI, so I'd be wary of enforcing cross-browser similarity if it removes one of those 'quirks'. Your choice though, and my answer does (I think) meet your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest that you don't need to worry about this, but to remove the placeholder text on focus (and to restore the `placeholder` on `blur`) I'd advise the following:

```
$('input').focus(
    function(){
        $(this).data('placeholder',this.placeholder).removeAttr('placeholder');
    }).blur(
        function(){
            $(this).attr('placeholder',$(this).data('placeholder')).data('placeholder','');
        });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ACAFY/).

The only reason to use the `$(this)[0]` notation is to 'break out' from the jQuery-fied `$(this)` object back to the native DOM node. To avoid doing that, it's easier to just `this`:

```
$('input').focus(
    function(){
        this.dataPlaceholder = this.placeholder;
        this.removeAttribute('placeholder');
    }).blur(
        function(){
            this.placeholder = this.dataPlaceholder;
            this.removeAttribute('dataPlaceholder');
        });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ACAFY/1/).

References:

- [`blur()` (jQuery)](http://api.jquery.com/blur).
- [`focus()` (jQuery)](http://api.jquery.com/focus).
- [`data()` (jQuery)](http://api.jquery.com/data).
- [`focus()` (jQuery)](http://api.jquery.com/focus).
- [`removeAttr()` (jQuery)](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr).
- [`removeAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.removeAttribute).

Comment: Didn't work for me which is strange. I tried using input, then the class of the inputs .signupFields as shown in the updated post and it didn't have any effect.

Comment: They both *seem* to work in JS Fiddle with your posted mark-up: [The first](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ACAFY/2/) and [the second](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ACAFY/3/). Is there anything logged in the error console of your browsers when you try with your full site/page?

Comment: Working now. Couldn't find the issue in chrome console so I tried in firefox and it said something about illegal character after the semi-colon after the closing bracket. Didn't see anything there though so I just used backspace until I was right beside the semi-colon. Tried again and it worked. Not sure what that was about. Thanks it's working fine.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad to have been of (mysteriously problematic) help =)

Answer (score 1):

assuming your html is like:

```
​<input id="username" type="text" placeholder="username"/>
​<input id="email" type="text" placeholder="email"/>
​<input id="password" type="text" placeholder="password"/>
```

your JS could be:

```
$("input").focusin(function() {
  $(this).data('placeholder',this.placeholder);//store the current placeholder
  this.placeholder = "";//no need for $(this)[0]
}).focusout(function() {
  this.placeholder = $(this).data('placeholder');//retrieve the stored placeholder
});​
```

this would target all of them with only one bit of code.

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JKirchartz/SGZNQ/

Comment: Not quite sure why this won't work for me. I even tried to use the class for the inputs and it has no effect.

Comment: I'm using jQuery 1.7 & it works find in my fiddle on Chrome 17